# Can't clear the inputs after submit - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to clear all the inputs after pressing the submit button. However, every time I click on submit, all the spaces still stay with their input values. The app is basically a sentence guesser where you have to guess the sentence displayed. If it's correct it should display the next button, and display another sentence. The app component is the following:

````
function App() {
  const [isNextVisible, setNextVisible] = useState(false);
  const [sentence, setSentence] = useState("");
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`###`)
      .then((response) => {
        let sentence = response.data.data.sentence;
        setSentence(sentence);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [count, sentence]);

  let mix = function (str) {
    let a = str.split("");
    let n = a.length;

    for (let j = n - 1; j > 0; j--) {
      let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (j + 1));
      let tmp = a[j];
      a[j] = a[x];
      a[x] = tmp;
    }
    return a.join("");
  };
  const shuffle = (str) => {
    if (str.length < 2) return str;
    let splitted = str.split(" ");
    let converted = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
      converted.push(mix(splitted[i]));
    }
    return converted.join(" ");
  };
  let shuffled = shuffle(sentence);
  let handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCount(count + 1);
    setScore(score + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="main-container">
        <h1>{shuffled}</h1>
        <p>Guess the sentence! Starting typing</p>
        <p>The Yellow Blocks are meant for spaces</p>
        <p>Score:{score}</p>
        <section className="input-container">
          <Input
            sentence={sentence}
            setNextVisible={setNextVisible}
            isNextVisible={isNextVisible}
            setScore={setScore}
            score={score}
          />
        </section>
        <section>{isNextVisible ? <button>next</button> : null}</section>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}```
````

**The input component is this one:**

```
function isValidCharacter(left = null, right = null) {
  return left && right && left.toUpperCase() === right.toUpperCase();
}

export default function Input(props) {
  const { sentence, setNextVisible } = props;
  const refFocus = React.useRef({});

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(Array(sentence.length).fill(""));
  const handleChange = (index) => (event) => {
    if (isValidCharacter(event.target.value, sentence[index])) {
      const nextFocus = index + 1;

      if (nextFocus in refFocus.current) {
        refFocus.current[nextFocus].focus();
      }
    }

    setValue((prev) => {
      const next = prev.slice(0);
      next[index] = event.target.value;
      return next;
    });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // compare inputs with the provided word
    if (value.join("").toLocaleLowerCase() === sentence.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
      setNextVisible(true);
    } else {
      setNextVisible(false);
    }
  }, [value, setNextVisible, sentence]);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {sentence.split("").map((character, index) => {
        const hasBackgroundGreen =
          value[index] === ""
            ? {}
            : isValidCharacter(value[index], character)
            ? { background: "#4caf50" }
            : { background: "#e1e1e1" };
        return (
          <input
            key={index}
            ref={(ref) => (refFocus.current[index] = ref)}
            type="text"
            value={value[index]}
            onChange={handleChange(index)}
            style={hasBackgroundGreen}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: if youre trying to clear inputs onSubmit, perhaps write a 'reset to initial state' function to be called in your handleSubmit

Comment: You are not clearing the `value` state inside your Input - so it keeps showing the previous result when you change the word.
As a side note, I'd keep the `shuffled` word in a state variable too, as you can see the shuffled word changing on every letter input.

Answer (score 0):

You do not interact with the values in the form in any way, you yourself set them value = {* value *}, so in order to change them you need:

As an option, add this to the code "Input" component

```
const {sentence, setNextVisible, score} = props;


useEffect(() => {
    setValue(Array(sentence.length).fill(""));
}, [score])
```